# How do I refresh the db connection using JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jooq

I have a use case where we have to silently replace the db with the changes made on one node in the cluster to the other node. The other node should not restart the process but should refresh the DB connection so that it gets the new changes when the db file(SQLite) has been replaced. Is there a way to do this in JOOQ ?. I have not found any relevant API to refresh the DB connection.

I tried to do the following but I get a deadlock -

```
public static void closeDBConnection(Configuration config) {
    try {
        Connection connection = getDBConnection(config);
        config.connectionProvider().release(connection);

        if (!connection.isClosed()) {
            connection.close();
        }
    } catch(SQLException ex) {
    //   throw new ReAttachException();
    }
}

public static Connection getDBConnection(Configuration config) {
    return config.connectionProvider().acquire();
}
```

In the calling method -

```
private void reattach(FooRecord record, Configuration config) {
    record.detach();

    DBUtils.closeDBConnection(config);
    DBUtils.getDBConnection(config);

    record.attach(config);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jOOQ doesn't manage your connection for you, you'll have to do that either yourself, or by using your JDBC drivers' or connection pool's capabilities.

In particular, in your current attempts, you're calling jOOQ's SPI `ConnectionProvider`, which you shouldn't call. An SPI is intended for you to *implement* and for jOOQ to *use* and call. This means that your implementation should already handle the connection replacement, and jOOQ shouldn't notice anything about that:

```java
class MyConnectionProvider implements ConnectionProvider {
    @Override
    public Connection acquire() {
        // Do your own reconnection magic here
        connection = ...

        // Pass this connection to jOOQ. jOOQ should assume it will always work.
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void release(Connection connection) {
        // Close or return to the pool, etc.
    }
}
```